# SQL Query in Access that lists values not in both tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to find out which drivers have not purchased fuel in the last 6 months.

I have two tables TransactionReport (all transactions from the last 6 months) and DriverList (all drivers)

```
TransactionReport
DriverID  |  DriverLastName | DriverFirstName | Other Columns not used for this query

DriverList
DriverID  |  DriverLastName | DriverFirstName | Other Columns not used for this query
```

I would like to return all the DriverID's listed in DriverList that are not listed in TransactionReport.

Results should look give me the following

```
DriverID  |  DriverLastName | DriverFirstName
```

Comment: If you are new to MS Access, you should be looking at the wizards. There is a find unmatched query wizard.

Comment: @Remou not new to access, the wizards suck so bad I usually write SQL statments but I'll give the wizard a shot.

Comment: Larry, it is better to use the wizards than to ask someone to write the sql for you. You should be able to improve the wizard sql if you are familiar with it.

Comment: @Remou that's what I do most of the time. I am new to Access 2007, have been using 2000 for a while now, it's looks like it was a simple as not knowing what to look for. I know how to do joins to find values in both tables but don't know how to find what's not in both tables.

Comment: Why does `TransactionReport` include `DriverLastName` and `DriverFirstName`?  It has `DriverID`, so you can use that to retrieve the names from `DriverList` when needed.

Comment: @HansUp I imported two spreadsheets as tables into access. The fuel company doesn't offer this report so I ran two reports and exported them to excel then imported those into the database. There may have been an easier way but I needed the info quickly and that's the only way I could think of to do this quickly. I would have never designed a DB that way :)

Comment: I find it immensely humorous that you are working on this and I'm the one working on a stroke education presentation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A left outer join getting only NULL result in the right table should work

```
select distinct driverlist.driverid, driverlist.driverlastname, driverlist.driverfirstname
from driverlist
left outer join transactionreport
on driverlist.driverid = transactionreport.driverid
where transactionreport.driverid is null
```

Comment: @Larry - Give the table an alias as in my answer or prefix the fields in the select with `driverlist.` to prevent this error.

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
    DriverID, DriverLastName, DriverFirstName

from
    DriverList

where
    DriverID not in (select DriverID from TransactionReport)
```

Comment: This did work, but it takes almost 20 seconds to run the query

Comment: 10293 in transactions, 716 in drivers.

Comment: I did upvote it was very straightforward and easy to understand. I chose il_guru answer as correct because it ran faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT dl.DriverID , dl.DriverLastName, dl.DriverFirstName FROM DriverList dl
 LEFT JOIN TransactionReport tr ON  dl.DriverID  = tr.DriverID  
WHERE tr.DriverID IS NULL
```

Comment: Oops and there me commenting on someone else mistake!

Answer (score 0):

You can do as mentioned earlier:

```
Select dl.DriverID , dl.DriverLastName, dl.DriverFirstName From DriverList dl
 LEFT Join TransactionReport tr on  dl.DriverID  = tr.DriverID  
WHERE tr.DriverID is Null
```

Which will work.  However, using an anti-semi join will get you faster results and a more readable query.  It seems later versions of MS Access support this:

```
SELECT dl.DriverID, dl.DriverLastName, dl.DriverFirstName From DriverList dl
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT tr.DriverID 
     FROM TransactionReport tr 
     WHERE tr.DriverID = dl.DriverID)
```

The key here is to pay attention to the WHERE inside the EXISTS statement.  The NOT logic is already in front of EXISTS, so you have to test for equality inside the statement.

Comment: Oops!  Missed revision.  Thank you.